# main function won't take any arguments in haskell

Tags: function, haskell, functional-programming

Hi I want to define a main function in haskell, similar to the main-function in java

```
main :: String -> IO()
main args = do
            putStrLn args
```

But this gives me an error when I try to run the program.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An Haskell program's entry point has the type of `IO ()`, not `String -> IO ()`.

To get the command-line arguments, use `System.Environment`'s [`getArgs`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/System-Environment.html#v:getArgs).

Using do-notation:

```
import System.Environment (getArgs)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  args <- getArgs
  print args
```

(Note that [`print`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:print) is used instead of [`putStrLn`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:putStrLn), since `args` have the type of `[String]`, and not `String`.)

Comment: Technically, the type just has to be some sort of `IO` value, not necessarily `IO ()`. There's just usually no *reason* to wrap any type other than `()`.

Answer (score 0):

I also found this very useful.

```
main :: IO ()
main =
    do
        input <- getContents
        solve input
```